# Where can i get exercises for 'Dive into Python'?

Tags: python

I'm learning python with 'Dive Into Python 3' and It's very hard to remember everything, without writing something, but there are no exercises in this book. So I ask here, where can i find them to remember everything better.

Answer (score 2):

I used [ProjectEuler.net](http://projecteuler.net/) when learning Python. It also helped sharpen my math skills.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [*How to Think Like a Computer Scientist*](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/index.html) instead of *Dive Into Python* to learn Python. The former has exercises in every chapter, is targeted for a more appropriate version of Python (Python 3 does not have the library support to make it compelling to use yet, and the version of DIP targeting Python 2 is quite old), and it does not have the reputations for errors and ugly code examples DIP has.

Answer (score 0):

Find a good Code Kata website:  Here's a list I compiled.

http://slott-softwarearchitect.blogspot.com/2009/08/code-kata-resources.html

I've also collected lots of exercises: http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/python.html  This book, however, covers only Python 2.6, so it may be more confusing than helpful.